# Failed to load TesseractTools in Mathematica 11 running on Raspberry Pi

Tags: bugs, image-processing, raspberry-pi, ocr

Version where this occurred:
Mathematica: 
Version - 11.0.1.0
Platform - Linux ARM (32-bit)

Raspbian: 
Version - September 2017
Release Date - 2017-09-07
Kernel Version - 4.9

Attempting to do OCR using "TextRecognize" on Mathematica. 
Get the following error:
Failed to load TesseractTools

Please advise on whether this is a known bug or whether I need to install any additional package to support. Btw, earlier had Mathematica 10 installed on the same system and TextRecognize worked fine.

Comment: I see the same problem. When you find a problem like this, it is best to [contact support directly](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/). This is not an official Wolfram site and they won't see your message here.

Comment: Known bug; the fix should be included in the next release.

Comment: @ilian Do you know if there will be a 11.2 for the RPi?

Comment: @ilian Also, unrelated: do you know if the trial version is already 11.2 final?

Comment: @Szabolcs Possibly, though no guarantees that the next RPi release will be exactly 11.2;  the trial version is not yet 11.2, but should be sometime in the coming week.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think the trial version is live now.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in the just released Mathematica 11.2.0 for the Raspberry Pi.

Note you may have to install a paclet manually first. It is not currently included in the installation in an effort to keep the footprint smaller.

```
$Version                                                                

(* 11.2.0 for Linux ARM (32-bit) (January 15, 2018) *)

PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[];                                      

PacletInstall["TesseractTools"]                                         

(* Paclet[TesseractTools, 11.2.27, <>] *)

TextRecognize[Rasterize["hello"]]                                       

(* "hello" *)
```